# PHP mail() is giving Network is unreachable in "Microsoft Azure VM"

Tags: php, azure, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to test mail to send out emails from my VM at Microsoft Azure but I'm getting this errors!

```
Nov  3 06:33:22 devvm postfix/smtp[10942]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.150.27]:25: Connection timed out
Nov  3 06:33:22 devvm postfix/smtp[10942]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c1c::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Nov  3 06:33:22 devvm postfix/smtp[10942]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Nov  3 06:33:22 devvm postfix/smtp[10942]: 4C7CABDD84: to=MyEmailRemoved@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=57498, delays=57437/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c00::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

What I've tried to do is enabled port 25 from azure, but can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: It's likely that Azure is blocking outbound SMTP traffic beyond your control – check their docs. Also you should be using port 465 or 587 for sending securely using PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

There is restriction of outbound SMTP connection from VMs. The direct SMTP connection from Azure is blocked to protect Azure data center public IP addresses from reputation abuse even if authenticated.

**The Outgoing email messages that are sent directly to external domains like `outlook.com` and `gmail.com` on TCP port 25 from a virtual machine is possible only when the VM is deployed in certain subscription types.**

Even for the **VMs which are deployed in the Pay-as-you-go subscriptions the outbound SMTP connections on TCP port 25 are blocked**. But you can remove this block if your Azure subscription is in good standing and has a sufficient payment history. You can request to have the restriction removed by going to the **Cannot send email (SMTP-Port 25)** section of the **Diagnose and Solve** blade for an Azure Virtual Network resource in the Azure portal.

Only for the virtual machines that are deployed in **Enterprise Agreement subscriptions**, the outbound SMTP connections on TCP port 25 will not be blocked.

As an workaround its recommended to use **authenticated SMTP relay services** to send email from Azure VMs. These relay services typically connect through TCP port 587. **SendGrid** is one such SMTP relay service, but there are others.

Read this [Sending Email with Microsoft Azure](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure-2021#create-a-twilio-sendgrid-account) document for detailed explanation on how to use SendGrid to send mails form Azure VMs.

And for more information on restriction of outbound SMTP connection from VM read this [Troubleshoot outbound SMTP connectivity problems in Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity).